# How to match a cell's delimited string with content from another sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, delimiter

Say if I had on one sheet, let's call it S1

```
 T1  1
 T2  3
 T3  4
 T5  6
 T4  2
```

And say I have this in a cell in S2

```
 T1;T2;T3;T4   10
```

Is it possible to use excel functions to go to S1, find T1, T2, T3, and T4 and sum the values that correspond to them?

So far I have functions capable of searching for one string and pulling data out of it, but I don't know how to do it for delimited strings, or if it's possible to do it at all

```
=SUMIF('2014'!$B:$B, J9, '2014'!$F:$F)
```

EDIT: If I do not know the range of my values. Should I just put very large numbers?

Comment: T1;T2;T3;T4 are all part of one cell and 10 is in a second cell (don't know how to make tables here...). 10 would be the sum. T1 1 are two cells, and T2 3 are also two separate cells. I apologize for the confusion,

Comment: Sorry - I realised that and deleted my comment.....just answering now.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first table is in `S1!A1:B5` and in `S2` sheet you have `T1;T2;T3;T4` in cell `A8` try this formula for the sum

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";"&'S1'!$A$1:$A$5&";",";"&A8&";"))+0,'S1'!$B$1:$B$5)`

`SEARCH` searches for each value from A1:A5 surrounded by ";" signs in `A8`, also surrounded by ; signs, if there's a match you get a number so `ISNUMBER` returns `TRUE` and `SUMPRODUCT` adds the relevant value from `B1:B5`

`SEARCH` is not case-sensitive - if you need it to be then use `FIND` instead

See screenshot - shown on one sheet for simplicity but it's the same formula

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it without knowing how many values I have? I will edit my question to  be more specific

Comment: Yes, you can use a large range like A1:A1000 or whatever - blank rows won't cause a problem for the formula

Comment: +1! great formula. But can you please explain why you've added `";"`? As for me, it should work even without it)

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";"&'2014'!$A$1:$A$5&";",";"&A8&";"))+0,'2014'!$B$1:$B$5) for whatever erasons Im getting 2014 as a result... The 2014 I have there is a substitute for S1, since my sheet is actually called 2014.

Comment: I suppose to be more specific, I'm trying to say, look at A8, and whatever is in there, search sheet 2014 for the content

Comment: That formula is working OK for me with sheet name 2014, can you try again?

Comment: @simoco - yes, for example data you don't need to use &";" but what if you have T4 and T42? - including the delimiters in the SEARCH stops confusion between strings which are substrings of other strings!